# Does For update lock subquery records?

Tags: apex, soql

I tried searching a little bit but haven't found the answer yet. 
Suppose I am having a query:

```
Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Name From OpportunityContactRoles) From Opportunity For Update
```

Will the For Update on the Opportunity lock the OpportunityContactRoles records as well? I tried to put For Update key word in the subquery but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You didn't see [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/135588)?

Comment: @sfdcfox No, I didn't see this. Thank you for pointing this to me. However, does that mean I have to introduce a separate query for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to update child records, the parents must [first be locked](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_deadlocks.htm); this happens automatically when you query records with locking statements or perform an update. It is generally unnecessary to lock the child records, as they cannot be updated in another thread until the parent lock is free.

However, as noted in the documentation, if you choose to do so, you must lock the parents and then the children to avoid deadlocks. You can't use `FOR UPDATE` in sub-queries, so if you want to lock those children, you would need to do so as a separate query. Simply locking the parent records *or* the child records should be sufficient in normal use cases.

Whichever technique you choose, however, make sure that you always query objects in the same order. The documentation (from above) says:

> As a developer, use care when locking rows to ensure that you are not introducing deadlocks. Verify that you are using standard deadlock avoidance techniques by accessing tables and rows in the same order from all locations in an application.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am not 100 percent sure whether we need to lock the child records because what we are doing is trying to delete the child records in future calls. So if two calls happen simultaneously, it will throw an exception. But it seems it should still touch the parent record so it should be fine I think

Comment: @LanceShi Before doing a DML, just make sure you perform a locking statement either on the Opportunity or the OpportunityLineItems. The lock will guarantee that neither transaction will fail as long as there's less than a five second wait.